# ACF get the value of an options field in a plugin

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin with the options add on.
How can I use the value of a field from options in a plugin?
I have a simple php file in the plugins folder that needs to get this value. Is that possible?

Comment: please elaborate more and put some sample code.

Comment: So I've created a custom field using ACF and I am able to display the results on a regular page, but I need to be able to get the value to output inside a php file in the plugins folder.

Comment: this is the code I am using to display this on a regular page
'<?php the_field('online_ordering_restaurant_name', 'option'); ?>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone searching for the solution:

Suppose your options field is a text field named "my_option_field_01".

In your php, if you wanted to display the value of that option field inside of a paragraph tag, you would put this:

```
<p><?php echo get_field('my_option_field_01', 'option'); ?></p>
```